# Positioning a box in the top right of a div using :after

Tags: css

I'm attempting to put a label on a div, essentially, using an :after psuedo class. Much like the [old bootstrap example blocks](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html)

[JS Fiddle illustrating what I'm trying](http://jsfiddle.net/xjoLw9n2/1/)

css:

```
.blah {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.blah:after {
    content: 'anyway';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1 px solid gray;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
```

Essentially, I want to stick the after box on the top right of the targeted div class, but instead it's popping up to the top right of body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their closest parent with position.

Adding `position: relative` to .blah fixes the issue.